# Updating Npm packages with unresolved Peer dependencies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-update

I am trying to update `react-router-dom` however when I try I get an ERR of course. The error `ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree`

npm update "popper.js" "bootstrap" "react-router-dom" :

```
Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer popper.js@"^1.16.1" from bootstrap@4.6.1
npm ERR! node_modules/bootstrap
npm ERR!   bootstrap@"^4.1.1" from the root project
```

npm update popper.js :

```
Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer popper.js@"^1.16.1" from bootstrap@4.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/bootstrap
npm ERR!   bootstrap@"^4.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: popper.js@1.16.1
npm ERR! node_modules/popper.js
npm ERR!   peer popper.js@"^1.16.1" from bootstrap@4.6.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/bootstrap
npm ERR!     bootstrap@"^4.1.1" from the root project
```

And it seems like Im stuck in this loop of not being able to update bootstrap because popper.js is behind and I can update popper.js because of bootstrap.

I am running `npm update "popper.js" | "bootstrap" | "react-router-dom"` independently.
But no matter what I do I get these same errors.

I am working inside a giant project with alot of dependencies that need updating so I cant just run an update on everything. Can someone explain how I can update the peer dependencies? Ive never done an update like this so any pointer in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to run script with flag `--legacy-peer-deps` it will skip checking peer dependency. Peer dependency should be installed manually in package.json.

[Read more about the flag.](https://www.querythreads.com/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-what-s-a-potential-use-case/)